# Installed Typecatcher Fonts Not Showing Up in Inkscape?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, desktop-environments, inkscape

I installed google fonts with Typecatcher, but they are not showing up in Inkscape.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in both Inkscape and GIMP. The font worked in LibreOffice but not these other applications. I installed the fonts with the common method of right-clicking on the font file, and then choosing `Open with Fonts` from the menu that pops up.

What I did is create a `.fonts` folder in the Home directory, and copy the font files there. Then they worked.

Folders that start with a `.` are normally hidden, as they contain system stuff and changing them can cause problems easily.  In the Files utility, you need to click on the icon with three bars on the right of the menu bar, and then click on the checkbox next to `Show Hidden Files`. Then make sure you are in the Home directory, go to that same menu and click the icon to create a new folder, and name it `.fonts`.

Now go to the `Downloads` folder, find the font files you want to install, make sure they have been unzipped, and then copy those files to the .fonts folder.